# Abaqus: The following parts have some elements without any section assigned / Composite Layups

Tags: set, element, abaqus

I am building up composite layups and assigning them to element sets. When I do so as soon as I try to submit the job, Abaqus always gives me the error "**The following parts have some elements without any section assigned**". There is not a single element without a material property, I do this by a script. As soon as I use a set which does not contain elements but a geometry Abaqus highlights the region green, but using geometry instead of element sets is not very suitable for me, because I am changing the properties of different elements. Also the region selection window opened by abaqus says "Sets below may contain elements, cells, shell faces or wire edges", so it should be possible to use element sets right?

I use the section assignment only for a small amount of elements, everything else is covered by composite layups.

If needed I can share more details from my model, but as I am not sure where to look for any errors right now, I wont do that right now.

Best regards and thanks for any advice!

Comment: I'd recommend you to look at the region which doesn't have any sections assigned from odb viewer. Navigate to `Output databases -- <your odb> --  Element Sets -- Warn/Err element set`. It is better to just create a `Set` with just elements and assign properties to that particular set.

Comment: there is one warning element set which is namend "WarnElementUserNormMatOrient"
Can't find anything on that on google. The results I am receiving seem to be okay. Do you know anything about that error?

Answer (score 0):

You can do data check and then in open generated odb in viewer. In opened odb you can find ErrElemMissingSection in 'Display groups'